# make user select atleast one check box in check box list validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I am trying to do validation of atleast selecting one check box in checkbox list. i am getting error like Control 'CheckBoxListDaysofWeek' referenced by the ControlToValidate property of 'cvDaysofWeeklist' cannot be validated. below is my asp code.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxListDaysofWeek" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="formatcheckboxlist" ValidationGroup="ReportSearch" CausesValidation="true">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Mon" Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Tue" Value="2" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Wed" Value="3" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Thu" Value="4" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Fri" Value="5" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Sat" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Sun" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                     <ams:AMSCustomValidator ID="cvDaysofWeeklist" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateDaysofWeekList" ControlToValidate="CheckBoxListDaysofWeek"
                                       Display="None" ValidationGroup="ReportSearch"
                                        Resource="Content" ResourceName="TAGSEARCH_TEXTBOXMANUFACTURESTARTDATEVALIDATOR" />
                                      <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vce_DaysofWeek" runat="server" TargetControlID="cvDaysofWeeklist" HighlightCssClass="HighlightField"></ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>`
```

and my javascript function is

```
 function ValidateDaysofWeekList(source, args) {
        var chkListDow = document.getElementById('<%= CheckBoxListDaysofWeek.ClientID %>');
        var chkListinputs = chkListDow.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i = 0; i < chkListinputs.length; i++) {
            if (chkListinputs[i].checked) {
                args.IsValid = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a CustomValidator, you should not set the ControlToValidate property on your CheckBoxList.

If you set the ControlToValidate to a CheckBoxList, .NET will raise an exception.

Comment: Thanks i removed. but looks like ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender does not work with customvalidator?

Comment: I usually stay away from ajaxToolkit and would not be able to help you there. You could define the validator in the codebehind page. Set OnServerValidate on your CustomValidator and define a function in your codebehind. More info here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx